# What is the priority between .sbt files?

Tags: sbt

[SBT documentation] says

> Put settings in a .sbt file in a project that isn't checked into version control, such as `<project>/local.sbt`. sbt combines the settings from multiple .sbt files, so you can still have the standard `<project>/build.sbt` and check that into version control.

However, if two .sbt files define the same setting, which one wins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of sbt 0.13.8, we [*might*](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.8/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Load.scala#L721-L723) load `*.sbt` files in alphabetical order, but I don't think we have documented this behavior to be true. Thus, it's likely an implementation detail at this point.

We do promise:

1. setting order within the same file
2. plugin dependencies specified by auto plugins
3. settings loaded by auto plugin, then settings in `*.sbt`

So I would recommend using auto plugin if possible. Another way of de-prioritizing a setting is to scope in `ThisBuild`. You can either use an auto plugin or some project to define:

```
organization in ThisBuild := "com.example"
```

Comment: What I wanted was to prioritize my settings in a fork without changing `build.sbt` of the upstream project. Of course, merge conflicts there would be both rare and easily resolved anyway, so it doesn't matter that much. The strange thing is that I'm getting `name` from `a.sbt` instead of `b.sbt` despite linked code.

Answer (score 1):

It's alphabetic ordering:

**a.sbt**

```
name := "a"
```

**b.sbt**

```
name := "b"
```

Test:

```
% sbt 'show name'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/dnw/.dotfiles/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/dnw/Desktop/t-2015-04-18.1551/project
[info] Set current project to b (in build file:/Users/dnw/Desktop/t-2015-04-18.1551/)
[info] b
```

Comment: I actually did try this before asking (with `build.sbt` and `publish.sbt`), since that was the obvious guess. Maybe I forgot to reload?

Comment: Yep, make sure you reload (or restart sbt).

Comment: What's the SBT version? I've tried exactly the same (with addition of `sbt.version=0.13.7` in `project/build.properties`) and I get `a` as the name.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I'm using 0.13.8, but I'm still getting `b` with 0.13.7. Can you test with 0.13.8 please?

Comment: I get `a` with 0.13.8 as well, strangely enough.

Comment: 1.3.13 im getting `a`